# How to disable write operation for Jolokia in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, jolokia

I have a Spring boot (v1.5.9) based application with Jolokia provided by Spring boot actuator.

Jolokia works fine. I can read values, for example:

http://localhost:8080/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=ClassLoading/Verbose

gives me:

```
{"request":{"mbean":"java.lang:type=ClassLoading","attribute":"Verbose","type":"read"},"value":false,"timestamp":1527859447,"status":200}
```

What I want is to disable writing operations, for example:

http://localhost:8080/jolokia/write/java.lang:type=ClassLoading/Verbose/true

The spring boot configuration looks like this:

```
management.security.enabled=false
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=* 
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=jolokia,metrics
management.endpoint.jolokia.config.policyLocation=classpath:/jolokia.xml
```

And the Jolokia's policy in WEB-INF\classes\jolokia.xml (in resulting war, according to https://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html) contains:

```
<restrict>
    <commands>
        <command>read</command>
        <command>list</command>
        <command>version</command>
        <command>search</command>
    </commands>
</restrict>
```

Despite this I see the following note in application's log:

```
jolokia: No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
```

And the write operation from the example above is working fine.

What I'm doing wrong? Should I put the policy file somewhere else? Is it possible to configure Jolokia's policy directly from the Spring boot configuration?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Spring Boot 1.5.9? If you are using Spring Boot 1.5.9, your configuration properties are wrong as they're all from 2.0.x. For example, if you want to configure Jolokia in Spring Boot 1.5.x you should use `jolokia.config.*`. There's more information in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-jolokia).

Comment: @AndyWilkinson good point! I've used configuration from the spring boot 2.0.x in my 1.5.9 application :( Changing the policyLocation configuration key fixes my problem. In logs, there is finally "jolokia: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia.xml" a write operation is disabled. Please copy your comment into answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've inadvertently used Spring Boot 2.0 configuration properties with Spring Boot 1.5.x. In 1.5 you should use `jolokia.config.policyLocation`. There's a little more information in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-jolokia).